# Decoding json data in swift with two different possible json reponse from server to two different structs

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, urlsession

When I make an api request through urlSession to the server I might get a json like

```
{
    "movie": "Avengers",
    "director": "Joss Whedon",
}
```

or like this

```
{
    "apiKey": "invalid"
}
```

I have two structs to save like this

```
struct Movie: Codable {
    let request: String
    let director: String

    init(movie:String, director:Sring) {
        self.movie = movie
        self.director = director
    }
}

struct Valid: Codable {
    let apiKey: String

    init(apiKey:String) {
        self.apiKey = apiKey
    }
}
```

Based on the response i want to either decode to first struct or the second struct. How to do that.

Comment: Not sure if this is the proper way you want to be letting the developer know if their API key is invalid. I think it'd be better if you threw and error if it's invalid, and if it's not then send the data. That way you don't have to worry about which struct gets decoded.

Comment: @JulesL. Thanks. But for some reason I have to go this way. How would i go about decoding?

Comment: Why would you save an invalid response? Just ignore "apiKey" in case the decoding doesn't succeed. Btw There is no request key one your JSON string and your structure it is missing the movie property.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let url = URL(string: "myurl.com") {
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
      if let data = data {
        guard let json = data as? [String:AnyObject] else {
              return
        }
          do {
            if let movie =  json["movie"]{
              //moview is there. so you can decode to your movie struct
              let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Movie.self, from: data)
            }else{
              //move is not there.it means error
              let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Valid.self, from: data)
            }
          } catch let error {
             print(error)
          }
       }
   }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse json with a single Struct like this

```
struct RootClass : Codable {

    let apiKey : String?
    let director : String?
    let movie : String?


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case apiKey = "apiKey"
        case director = "director"
        case movie = "movie"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        apiKey = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .apiKey)
        director = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .director)
        movie = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .movie)
    }


}
```

And check the value of key apiKey if it's nil then use movies and director. or use the value of apiKey

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the **`Codable`** types to parse the above 2 *JSON* responses should look like,

```
struct Movie: Decodable {
    let movie: String
    let director: String
}

struct Valid: Decodable {
    let apiKey: String
}
```

There is no need to explicitly create `init()`. `Codable` will handle that automatically.

Next, you need to create another `Codable` type that can handle both the responses, i.e.

```
enum Response: Decodable {
    case movie(Movie)
    case valid(Valid)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            let data = try container.decode(Movie.self)
            self = .movie(data)
        } catch  {
            let data = try container.decode(Valid.self)
            self = .valid(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can parse the *JSON* `data` like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```